# cannot resolve symbol okhttp

Tags: android, okhttp

i am developing a gcm chat app in android studio and i am getting this error n no idea how to resolve it. i searched about it but didn't find any thing.
Here is the code and in MainActivity.java also having same problem.

```
package com.example.jason.androidchat2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;


public class ChatActivity extends Activity {

EditText editText_mail_id;
EditText editText_chat_message;
ListView listView_chat_messages;
Button button_send_chat;
List<ChatObject> chat_list;

BroadcastReceiver recieve_chat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    editText_mail_id= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mail_id);
    editText_chat_message= (EditText)       findViewById(R.id.editText_chat_message);
    listView_chat_messages= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_chat_messages);
    button_send_chat= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send_chat);
    button_send_chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // send chat message to server
            String message=editText_chat_message.getText().toString();

            showChat("sent",message);

            new SendMessage().execute();

            editText_chat_message.setText("");


        }
    });


    recieve_chat=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String message=intent.getStringExtra("message");

            Log.d("pavan","in local braod "+message);
            showChat("recieve",message);


        }
    };

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(recieve_chat, new IntentFilter("message_recieved"));



}

private void showChat(String type, String message){

    if(chat_list==null || chat_list.size()==0){

        chat_list= new ArrayList<ChatObject>();
    }

    chat_list.add(new ChatObject(message,type));

    ChatAdabter chatAdabter=new ChatAdabter(ChatActivity.this,R.layout.chat_view,chat_list);

    listView_chat_messages.setAdapter(chatAdabter);
    //chatAdabter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String url = Util.send_chat_url+"?email_id="+editText_mail_id.getText().toString()+"&message="+editText_chat_message.getText().toString();
        Log.i("pavan", "url" + url);

        OkHttpClient client_for_getMyFriends = new OkHttpClient();;

        String response = null;
        // String response=Utility.callhttpRequest(url);

        try {
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            response = callOkHttpRequest(new URL(url),
                    client_for_getMyFriends);
            for (String subString : response.split("<script", 2)) {
                response = subString;
                break;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Toast.makeText(context,"response "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}

// Http request using OkHttpClient
String callOkHttpRequest(URL url, OkHttpClient tempClient)
        throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection connection = tempClient.open(url);

    connection.setConnectTimeout(40000);
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        // Read the response.
        in = connection.getInputStream();
        byte[] response = readFully(in);
        return new String(response, "UTF-8");
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
    }
}

byte[] readFully(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

}

Comment: OkHttp is a third party library and not natively available in the SDK. You will need to download either the JAR file and put in the project libs folder or add the `compile...` statement in your project gradle file. Here are the options: http://square.github.io/okhttp/#download

Comment: thanks it worked but 
    String callOkHttpRequest(URL url, OkHttpClient tempClient)
    throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection connection = tempClient.open(url);



error at cannot resolve symbol open.

Answer (score 7):

**[OkHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)** is an Open Source project designed to be an efficient HTTP client.

Just add this in your **`build.gradle`**

```
    dependencies {
    
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
}
```

### FYI

The latest release is available

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
```

Comment: it give me error failed to resolve com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0

Comment: you can use `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'`

Comment: i added .jar file as mentioned in above comment but  when i used open method its says cannot resolve method open . any idea???

Comment: did you properly added ? did you click it "As a library" .Then clean and rebuild with sync (do gradle) your project

Comment: i directly drag n drop it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95840/discussion-between-mayur-raikwar-and-intellij-amiya).